# How to get one column result in one row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a column result in a single row. Is it possible in MySql
say I

```
Select name from users where city = 'NewYork'
```

now this will result in

```
name
mak
sandy
john
```

Can I get the result in this

```
name  
mak,sandy,john
```

I Mysql concat_ws() function does concat but its  not showing me result.

Comment: `concat_ws()` is a per-row operation. you need `group_concat()`, which works over multiple rows: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may want to use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name FROM users WHERE city = 'NewYork';
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE users (name varchar(10), city varchar(10));
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('mak', 'NewYork');
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('sandy', 'NewYork');
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('john', 'NewYork');
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('paul', 'Washington');
```

Result:

```
+----------------+
| name           |
+----------------+
| mak,sandy,john |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ',') FROM users WHERE city = 'NewYork'
```

suit you ?